# Even when value set: TypeError at /admin/products/product/1/change/ argument must be int or float

Tags: python, django-models

When i use the models.DecimalField and specify (max_digits=10, decimal_places=2), I receive the error TypeError at/admin/products/product/1/change/argument must be int or float when trying to access it through the admin page.

If i remove (max_digits=10, decimal_places=2) and just put in a TextField() it works, therefore models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2) throws and error but models.TextField() doesnt.

Any idea?

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

the error:

```
TypeError at /admin/products/product/1/change/
argument must be int or float
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/products/product/1/change/
Django Version: 2.2.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
argument must be int or float
Exception Location:
```

Comment: Well that usually mwans that you assign a string to your decimal field. Can you provide the view that causes the error?

Comment: Update: when changing to price = models.FloatField() it also removes the error.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry for my "noobness", I'm on a very steep learning curve at the moment and appreciate your help. When you say, provide the view? Do you mean the view of the error within the browser?

Answer (score 2):

to fix this error delete your *pychache* from migrations folder and also from your project folder but leave the *init*.py file as it is. also delete the sqlite database file (db.sqlite3) and then quit the server (if running), after that run the following command (in cmd or in your terminal )

```
python manage.py makemigrations 


python manage.py migrate
```

then you need to create the superuser again. by following commmand

`python manage.py createsuperuser` (fill all the entries and then run the server)

good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, by increasing the max_digits it worked!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue. fixed by increasing the max_digits and running `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.